# What is considered a system call?

Tags: operating-system, system-calls

is using os.mknod(), os.rename(), os.mkdir(), etc. considered a system call?

I'm trying to understand exactly what a system call entails.

Answer (score 0):

A system call is generally considered to be one that is dispatched through the system interrupt vector or an equivalent mechanism (such on Intel processors).